# How is ship cost determined?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've been paying more attention to the cost of certain ships. It would seem obvious that the more slots a ship has, the more expensive it will be. However, there seems to be a lot of inconsistencies with this. The jump from 15 to 20 slots may only be 800,000 Units, but from 20-30 becomes 5 million Units.

Is there a set calculation for how much ships cost? Does affiliation with a race determine how expensive their ships may be?

Comment: I don't know how much it factors in, but the equipment (mining beams, photon cannons, upgrades, etc.) on your current ship affect the price of ships you might want to buy, from what I've seen. Not sure why that's the case, as it seems irrelevant, but from anecdotal evidence that seems to be the case.

Comment: The problem with your example is that a ship's cost / slots ratio isn't linear but exponential. That doesn't mean there are inconsistencies but it means it isn't "slots * [some amount]" to determine the price.

Comment: I came across a 45 slot ship for 51,280,384 Units...http://imgur.com/H73kkY2

Comment: I was at one space station where I found a ship with a lot more slots than my current one and at a lot lower price than I usually found for ships with just one more slot. I passed on it only because I had just loaded 3 warp cells into my drive, but at the next two systems, the prices I got were much worse. The only difference I can think applies is that the first station was run by the Gek and the others since then have all been Vy’keen. I found an outpost once where I was able to endlessly get favors from a Gek because every 4th speech he'd give me 79 Carbon. Learned 100+ words in 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each additional slot increases the cost by a *factor*. I don't have exact values. It may be similar to the exosuit upgrades, in which you pay 10k for the first, 10k * 2 for the second, 10k * 3 for the third, etc. Obviously ships have higher cost per slot, but the idea is that it scales as the slots increase. It's not mathematically exponential, but it gets pricey quite fast.

This applies to the baseline, non-upgraded, per-slot cost. As MageXy commented, the value of any upgrades is also added to the price. I've seen identical ships with the same slot count but different upgrades sell for different prices. At 25 slots, two ships differed by at least a million credits, so upgrades can make quite a difference. I'd prefer a non-upgraded ship most of the time anyway, as found/bought ships tend to be a mess in terms of component linking. YMMV.

Comment: I don't know how valid this is, but multiple users on Reddit claimed that different ships also handle differently: cargo ships tend to turn more sluggishly and more fighter-like ships tend to be much more agile.